# How to do "Insert into Non-key Column on Duplicate Update" in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I knew that there're a syntax to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in mysql, that is you do with the primary or unique key column: Ex:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

But how can we do for the non-key column.

Suppose I have a simple table Tb1 (C1, C2)

```
C1 - C2
1 - 1
2 - 1
3 - 1
```

And if I insert `1` into column `C1`  then it will add (1, 2) into the table, with 2 is the the increase 1 from the previous value of 1:

```
C1 - C2
1 - 1
1 - 2
2 - 1
3 - 1
```

And if I insert `1` into column `C1` again  then it will add (1, 3) into the table, with 3 is the the increase 1 from the previous value of 2 :

```
C1 - C2
1 - 1
1 - 2
1 - 3
2 - 1
3 - 1
```

So, By just 1 query, How to do "Insert into Non-key Column on Duplicate Update" in Mysql?

Note: actually the C1 column is the foreign key refer to other table, mainTb (C1). But i don't want to insert data into mainTb.

Comment: If you use a MyISAM engine, you can use auto_increment as part of a compound PRIMARY KEY. The manual explains how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a cool solution, but don't need to use Duplicate.

```
insert into Tb1 (c1,c2) select 1, if(max(c2) is null,1, max(c2)+1) from Tb1 where c1=1
```

working
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d1317/1